# Undefined index: quantity in commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_validate()

Tags: commerce

This may be some simple question, How to show the `Add to cart` button on the custom page,
I have listed the products in the custom page by programmatically, but displaying the "Add to Cart" button makes problem,

As I have displays the cart button using the below code,

```
  $line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new($productinfo);
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_line_item', $line_item);
  $line_item->data['context']['product_ids'] = $productid;
  $line_item->quantity = 1;
  $qty = 1;
  $form_id = commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_id(array($productid), $qty);
  $addtocart_form = drupal_get_form($form_id, $line_item);
  print render($addtocart_form);
```

it shows the `Add to cart` button but while clicking this, I got the below error,

```
Notice: Undefined index: quantity in commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_validate() (line 2088 of \commerce\modules\cart\commerce_cart.module).
You must specify a valid quantity to add to the cart.
Notice: Undefined index: #datatype in commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_validate() (line 2094 of \commerce\modules\cart\commerce_cart.module).
Notice: Undefined index: line_item_fields in commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_validate() (line 2107 of \commerce\modules\cart\commerce_cart.module).
Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array in field_default_extract_form_values() (line 36 of \modules\field\field.default.inc).
Recoverable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to drupal_array_get_nested_value() must be an array, null given, called in \modules\field\field.default.inc on line 38 and defined in drupal_array_get_nested_value() (line 6811 of \includes\common.inc)
```

I think this error comes because of `quantity` field not in the `add to cart form`, how to add the quantity field in the `add to cart form`,

I am using drupal commerce,

what is wrong in my code?

thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I remember you can use 'Add to cart form' as a formatter in your product's display - isn't it much easier? (Or I'm forgettingg something)

Comment: i am listing this in home page,now i have no idea how to show addtocart button.., i am new to drupal commerce, can u help to show addtocart button